# Is there away to avoid "double" double quotes in sparql replace expression

Tags: sparql, normalize, graphdb

I'm running a SPARQL query against the graphdb SPARQL endpoint where I do some normalization and splitting of resources. Problem is that the double quotes I'm adding becomes doubled in the output. Like this:

`http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/M0000259,"Acrodynia"",""Feer Disease"",""Feers Disease"",""Pink Disease"",""Swift Disease"",""Swifts Disease"",""Acrodynic Erythema"",""Chronic Childhood Mercurialism"",""Feers Disease"",""Swifts Disease"",""Erythema"","" Acrodynic"",""Childhood Mercurialism"","" Chronic"",""Childhood Mercurialisms"","" Chronic"",""Chronic Childhood Mercurialisms"",""Mercurialism"","" Chronic Childhood"`

The SELECT part of my query looks like this

`SELECT ?concept (replace(group_concat(replace(?label, "[\\u0022\\u0027\\u0060\\u00B4\\u2018\\u2019\\u201C\\u201D]", "");separator=","), ",", "\",\"") as ?labels)`

When I use other replace characters they don't get doubled in the output. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: you can use single quotes like `'string'` for everything that can be wrapped in double quotes. Or is this not what you're asking for?

Comment: in the end, you want to have double quotes around each label in the comma separated list, right?

Comment: `SELECT ?s (group_concat(concat("\"", str(?label),"\"");separator=",") as ?labels)
` - I omitted the replace of the special characters here for simplicity, but is this what you need? I did the wrapping inside quotes before the group concat aka list creation happens

Comment: I want to avoid the double quotes. Ie. don't want: ,""Feers Disease"", but ,"Feers Disease", And - I need the replace from , to ",", ie. I can'not first concat quotes and do replacement since the comma needs to be replaced with dquote,dquote

Comment: may I ask you where you see those double quotes? Just in the browser? That might just be due to rendering in the browser to show that those are string literals. For me it's difficult to reproduce since I don't have a running GraphDB instance, but you can try this query on http://dbpedia.org/sparql   : `SELECT ?s (group_concat(str(?label);separator="\",\"") as ?labels) {?s a owl:Class . ?s rdfs:label ?label}` - there are no double quotes around the labels

Comment: And if you want the comma in double quotes, why are you not using `separator="\",\""`? this would avoid to use a `replace` of the comma with double quotes comma double quotes

Answer (score 0):

I like the solution of UninformedUser. You can use single quotes around the strings to avoid escaping:

`group_concat(concat('"',?label,'"'); separator=',')`